# How to copy a file from one location to another location in S3 after removing header and trailer

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-s3

I have a file of around 2 GB in a S3 folder which contains header and trailer of different length and actual data is of different length. I need to copy this file to another location in S3 programmatically after removing header and trailer. Can anyone help me with this ?

File format (say file name abc.txt)=>

```
001|20210930|abc.txt
12345|abcsd|prsdf|20210930|10.0|50
12346|sdfgsd|dfg|20210930|20.0|100
12347|dfgfrg|dfg|20210930|30.0|200
009|3
```

1. I tried loading file from S3 in pandas but it got failed because of memory error. So can't use pandas here.
2. I tried using boto3 library and used  `obj.get()['Body'].read()` but how to remove header and trailer from this data and then write back to the file in S3?

Is there any other effective way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume you have some functions `is_header(line)` and `is_trailer(line)` that can tell you whether the line is a header or trailier, respectively.  Then here's how you could stream the file from S3 and save it back.

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client("s3")
bucket = "mybucket"
key = "path/to/abc.txt"
new_key = "path/to/def.txt"

r = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
sb = r["StreamingBody"]

content = [line for line in sb.iter_lines() if not is_header(line) and not is_trailer(line)]
content = b"".join(content)
r = s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=new_key, Bytes=content)
```

### Stream Data to Avoid Out of Memory Errors

The above code assumes that the entire file can fit into memory, which I assume it can because it's only 2 GB. If not you'll need to use [Multipart Uploads](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/uploadobjusingmpu.html).

Here's one way to do that using a [TransferManager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/mpu-upload-object.html)

```py
from typing import Optional
import boto3
from boto3.s3.transfer import TransferConfig
import botocore

MB = 1024*1024

class FileNoHeader:
    """Wrapper for a botocore StreamingBody to filter headers/trailers"""
    
    def __init__(self, stream: botocore.response.StreamingBody):
        self.stream = stream
        self.first_line = True
        self.line_generator = self.stream.iter_lines()

    def read(self, size: Optional[int] = None) -> bytes:
        """Wrap StreamingBody.iter_lines to read line-by-line while making it look like a fileobj
        
        Parameters
        ----------
        size: int, optional
            How much data to read. This is a minimum amount because we are using
            StreamingBody.iter_lines to read the file line by line, we can only return
            whole lines. If `None`, the default, read the entire file.
            This parameter is for compatibilty with the read() method of a file-like object
        """
        data = []
        amt = 0
        line = b""
        while size is None or amt < size:
            try:
                line = next(self.line_generator)
            except StopIteration:
                if line:
                    amt += len(line)
                    data.append(line)
                break
            if self.is_header(line) or self.is_trailer(line):
                line = b""
                continue
            amt += len(line)
            data.append(line)
        return b"\n".join(data)

    def close(self):
        """Close the underlying StreamingBody"""
        self.stream.close()
        
    def is_header(self, line):
        # TODO: implement your logic
        # right now just skips the first line
        if self.first_line:
            self.first_line = False
            return True
        return self.first_line

    def is_trailer(self, line):
        # TODO: implement your logic
        return False


## Usage
config = TransferConfig(multipart_chunksize=1*MB)
s3 = boto3.client("s3")

bucket = "mybucket"
key = "path/to/abc.txt"
new_key = "path/to/abc_no_header.txt"

r = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
streaming_body = r["Body"]
data_stream = FileNoHeader(streaming_body)

def tcback(bytes_transferred):
    print(f"{bytes_transferred} bytes transferred")

s3.upload_fileobj(
    data_stream,
    bucket,
    new_key,
    Config=config,
    Callback=tcback
)
```

#### Sidebar: AWS Lambda

If you are using AWS Lambda functions, you can have [up to 10 GB of memory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html#function-configuration-deployment-and-execution). You can [set the memory in the AWS Console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-function-common.html#configuration-memory-console) or using [the API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_UpdateFunctionConfiguration.html). Here're the docs for [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.update_function_configuration) and the [AWS CLI v2](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/lambda/update-function-configuration.html).

Comment: I tried something similar but the problem is since we are storing in the list => ```content = [line for line in sb.iter_lines() if not is_header(line) and not is_trailer(line)]```, it's failing because of "Out of Memory". Can i somehow read as a a stream and also write as a stream to S3 location?

Comment: How much memory do you have? I am surprised you do not have at least 2 GB.

Comment: I added new code that should be able to stream data and filter out headers/footers while avoiding "Out of Memory" errors.

Comment: I am able to make it work with the Transfer Manager. Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm glad you got it to work. Would you please mark the answer as accepted or upvote?